# Determine the JVM vendor in Gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I know about `JavaVersion.current()` to determine the JVM version being used.  But is there a way to determine whether the JVM is from Oracle, OpenJDK, etc?

Yes, there is always the option to check the system prop `"java.vendor"`, but since Gradle already handles this for the Java version I wonder if there is a convenience for provider as well?

Comment: No. I believe checking `java.vendor` is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from the [Source Code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/search?q=%22java.vendor%22&type=Code), there is no convenience function to retrieve the Java vendor string. Gradle relies on system property `java.vendor` as well in internal code.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do the same, and the System properties were the best way to do it. Here's an example of putting several system properties into the manifest of the jars being assembled.

```
tasks.withType(Jar){
    manifest.attributes.putAll([
"java-vm-specification-version": System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version"),
        "java-vm-specification-vendor" : System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.vendor"),
        "java-vm-specification-name"   : System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.name"),
        "java-vm-version"              : System.getProperty("java.vm.version"),
        "java-vm-vendor"               : System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.vendor"),
        "java-vm-name"                 : System.getProperty("java.vm.name"),
        "java-specification-version"   : System.getProperty("java.specification.version"),
        "java-specification-vendor"    : System.getProperty("java.specification.vendor"),
        "java-specification-name"      : System.getProperty("java.specification.name")
    ])
}
```